# using package name to create objects in Java

Tags: java, object, package

I was looking at someone's else code and they code it using package names.

```
String filename = "";

java.io.PrintWriter writer;

writer = new java.io.PrintWriter(new java.io.FileWriter(filename));
```

Is the syntax the equivalent had it not been coded with package name? Is there any use coding it with package names since Java allows it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the package names (or "fully-qualified names" - this refers to the package name and the class name together) if:

1. You need to use two classes of the same name in the same source file.
2. You didn't `import` the classes you're using for whichever reason. (Usually insanity.)
3. You `import`ed the classes but are still using the package names anyway because I don't know.

Comment: wo classes of the same name in the same source file. so it is possible  to code it like that(still would look like insanity). thanks!

Comment: @Nicholas It's a perfectly valid way to write Java, it's just - in my experience - very, very rarely *necessary*, and less readable than using `import`s to anyone with a passing familiarity with the JDK. Hence the "insanity" comment.

Answer (score 7):

Using [*fully-qualified names*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) is semantically the same as if the given classes were *imported*.

One possible usage of FQNs is if you need to work with two classes with same names, but in different 
packages.

```
import java.util.Date;

Date date = new Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could *not* use the package name and the code would still be exactly the same, you would just have to import the class from package `java.io` at the top of your program:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;

String filename = "";
PrintWriter writer;

writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write the class name including its package as a way to avoid ambiguities, say there are two classes named PrintWriter in your program writing `java.io.PrintWriter` will take the one from java.io.

It's not really a surprise that even in the "standard" classes there are quite some duplicate names - eg Date exists in java.util and java.sql, Queue exists in java.util and javax.jms - so you will encounter this construct from times to times.

Comment: oh I see! That's pretty neat of Java!